# House Wrap on Cantilevered Overhang

Tags: house-wrap

I have a cantilevered overhang on my second floor which I recently re-insulated.  In order to remove the old insulation, I had to remove the wood soffit and house wrap where the soffit was (the house has vinyl siding). Currently, I put up primed soffit with screws and caulk so that it was closed in, understanding that it could be a temporary solution. I'm assuming I need to replace the house wrap, if so, what is the best way to piece it together (I just cut it at the 90 degree angles)?

Comment: Of the 2 cantilever structures I have built did not have wrap on the bottom. I thought it would be a good idea but the engineer that put his stamp on both said it could and would cause more moisture problems. That was back in the 90's . So ideas may have changed. Both were 24" or less don't know if this matters.

Comment: Thanks Ed, this cantilever is only 16", and was built in 1982.  I'm not certain whether it is still needed/required, but I assume that if it wasn't required back then, the builder would have skipped it to cut corners.

Answer (score 1):

House wrap is important to stop moisture that might make it through the siding, driving rain, wind, siding sometimes cracks, the wrap will protect the plywood and help with wind pushing into the walls, when you put it back staple it on the tape the joints with the proper tape.eg; if it's typar then get typar tape.

Comment: Yes, I do see it's benefit for siding, and I didn't remove any there.  I just removed enough under the overhang to get in the new insulation.  It probably won't hurt to replace the 16" of it on the underside of the overhang, I just wasn't sure if it was needed.